# Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 not showing up

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am running Windows 7 64bit and Eclipse 32 bit.

The problem is that the Google button with the g icon in the Eclipse toolbar does not show up after I finish installing `GPE 3.7` and `GWT SDK 2.5.1` plugin. When I go to `Preferences`, there should be a google tab, but that does not show up either. When I go to **File menu -> New ->** I should see **Web Application Project** but I do not see that. When I go **Window -> Customize Perspective** and then Tool Bar Visibility tab, I do not see a Google tree item there.

I have reset my perspective by going **Window menu > Reset Perspective...**. I have even restarted Eclipse many times after installation.

There was no problems with the installation. If I go to **Eclipse -> About Eclipse -> Installation details**, I see `Google App Engine Java SDK 1.8.1`, `Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7`, and `Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.5.1` alongside all the other plugins that I have installed listed.

Can anyone kindly help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was running Windows 7 64bit, so needed to install 64bit version of Eclipse.

Comment: This also seems to apply to Mac OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out, that all my Eclipse files (including eclipse.ini) were set to read-only. After making all files writable, Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 showed up.

Comment: I have checked all my eclipse files and they have write access. It is still not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I know its bit late . But it would be helpful to someone. I too faced same issue and resolved it. This is how Iresolved my eclipse was 32- bit and my Java version was 64 bit . I uninstalled my JRE and installed 32 bit 1.8 JRE version and I was able to see GWT .